# python max integer limit - how's possible

Tags: python

As I understood, on Python 3.0+ there's no limit to the integer value. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers))

I was just wondering: how is that possible? I mean, there's no infinite memory neither infinite PC storage.

Comment: You are mixing two different limits, the Python limitation (None) and the hardware limitation. BTW: There might be more of them.

Comment: To get to an infinite number you also need infinite time and infinite storage. That's possible in maths but not in the real world e.g. in CPUs.

Comment: Cheeky answer: Proof by contradiction. Suppose N is the largest integer; but N+1 is also an integer, and it's bigger than N. Source: Ancient Greeks. See more reasonable answers about hardware limits for proper answer.

Comment: If instead, the `sys.maxint` constant was not removed, there might not be enough memory to store it in your PC.